# Can't have selected tab font color to black

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors, tabs

I am trying to design some tabs using CSS and following this [post](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/tabs/). Unfortunately, I can't manage to have the selected tab font color to black.

I have created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/) to describe the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header"> 

    <h1>Tabs</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
        <li id="selected"><a href="#">That</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#header li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    /* border-bottom-width: 0; */
    margin: 2px 2px 0 0;
    background: black;
}

#header li a {
    color: white;
}

#header #selected {
    position: relative;
    /* top: 1px; */
    background: white;
}

#header #selected li a {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/1/

```
#header #selected li a {
    color: black;
}
```

this addresses a `<* id="header"><* id="selected"><li><a>`.

What you want to select is a `<* id="header"><li id="selected"><a>`.

So use:

```
#header li#selected a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: @JVerstry You asked nearly two hours ago, so I commented an hour later

Comment: No worry, I always come back to my questions to accept answers, sooner or later...